# Changing libraryDependencies for specific code segments in SBT?

Tags: sbt, apache-spark

I am building a Spark project with SBT.

When I include a *libraryDependencies*, one part of the program will work, the other part will throw an Exception (because of a wrong version specified in the `libraryDependencies`). When I remove `libraryDependencies` it is the other way around.

Is there a way to dynamically change the `libraryDependencies` (changing a version) at compile or runtime?

Similar to that (pseudocode):

```
libraryDependencies.set("org.apache.hadoop.hadoop-client", "2.0.0-cdh4.5.0")

// here comes the code depending on hadoop-client" % "2.0.0-cdh4.5.0

libraryDependencies.set("org.apache.hadoop.hadoop-client", "1.0.4")

// here comes the code depending on hadoop-client" % "1.0.4
```

Could this be done by [scoping](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html)?

Comment: How can you expect to have different versions of the libraries at compile and runtime?! You may have different settings based upon other settings, but what you're after doesn't make sense to me. Need more help to understand the question. What would you like to add in the different CodeBlocks? I think you need different modules, effectively creating [a multi-project build](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @JacekLaskowski
Maybe I should have phrased it better, I want to depend on different libraries at different parts of the program. (Here: I want to read from HDFS using one version of a library and then writing this file to Cassandra using another (mapreduce) version of the library. Is this possible with a multi-project build?

Comment: You should add the comment to the question as it makes it so much easier to understand. You should definitely use multi-project build where there are two modules - HDFS reader and Cassandra writer. They're separate as you've pointed out (not only because of the libraries they use).

Comment: @JacekLaskowski ok I understand, I created a test project, however I could not find any good documentation on how to call the two modules in a main file. So I created another question on it, could you have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183074/multi-project-sbt-how-to-pass-argument-from-one-subproject-to-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need two versions - `1.0.4` and `2.0.0-cdh4.5.0` - of the same dependency `org.apache.hadoop.hadoop-client` in a single project it begs for a multi-module build configuration with two modules that each contain the code that relies on either dependency.

In one project, say `projectA` you'd have the `1.0.4` dependency and the code that uses it while in another, say `projectB` `2.0.0-cdh4.5.0` with the other part of the code.

With that said, **build.sbt** could look as follows:

```
lazy val projectA, projectB = project

libraryDependencies in projectA += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "1.0.4"

libraryDependencies in projectB += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.0.0-cdh4.5.0"
```

With the build configuration, you follow code/module separation.

You could also have these `libraryDependencies` settings defined in `build.sbt` of each project and the final result would be the same as above.