# How to use object/type from one subproject in another in multi-project build in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following multi-project folder structure:

```
/ComponentA/ComponentA.scala
/ComponentA/build.sbt
/ComponentB/ComponentB.scala
/ComponentB/build.sbt
/project/Build.scala
main.scala
```

In the root object `main.scala` the following should happen: `ComponentA` returns a String message that `ComponentB` reads in and prints out.

Here are the contents of the files:

**ComponentA**

```
object ComponentA {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var myMessage : String = "this message should be passed to ComponentB";
    println("Message to forward: %s \n\n\n ".format(myMessage))
    return myMessage;
  }
}
```

**ComponentB**

```
object ComponentB {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("\n\n\n Inside ComponentB! \n\n\n ")
    println("Message received: %s \n\n\n ".format(args(0)))
  }
}
```

**Build.scala**

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object RootBuild extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project(id = "root", base = file("."))
    .dependsOn(ComponentA, ComponentB)

  lazy val ComponentA = Project(id = "ComponentA", base = file("ComponentA"))

  lazy val ComponentB = Project(id = "ComponentB", base = file("ComponentB"))
    .dependsOn(ComponentA)

}
```

**main.scala**

```
object ComponentB {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    println("\n\n\n Inside main! \n\n\n ")

    // THIS SHOULD HAPPEN:
    // ComponentB(ComponentA());

  }
}
```

Is this possible with that project structure? If so, how will the code be for `main.scala`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `build.sbt` in the root project should let you create that project structure.

```
lazy val ComponentA = project

lazy val ComponentB = project dependsOn ComponentA

lazy val root = project in file(".") dependsOn (ComponentA, ComponentB) aggregate (ComponentA, ComponentB)
```

You'll have to fix a few issues in the component objects so they compile, but the project's classpath should be fine.

It is however a common approach to have a root project an aggregate for submodules so in your case `root` should not have `dependsOn` with another separate project `ComponentAB` that would `dependsOn ComponentB` (and hence `ComponentA` as `ComponentB` already depends on it).

*The code below should be taken with a great care and only for the sake of the question.*

**ComponentA/ComponentA.scala**

```
object ComponentA {
  def apply(): String = {
    var myMessage = "this message should be passed to ComponentB"
    println(s"Message to forward: $myMessage\n\n\n")
    myMessage
  }
}
```

**ComponentB/ComponentB.scala**

```
object ComponentB {
  def apply(msg: String) = {
    println("\n\n\n Inside ComponentB! \n\n\n ")
    println("Message received: $msg\n\n\n")
  }
}
```

**Main.scala**

```
object MainObject {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("\n\n\n Inside main! \n\n\n ")
    //ComponentB(ComponentA())
    ComponentA()
  }
}
```

With the files, when you do `run` you should get the following output:

```
[root]> run
[info] Running ComponentB



 Inside main!



Message to forward: this message should be passed to ComponentB



[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 20, 2014 9:59:32 PM
```

Comment: To test your suggestion, what would you put as main.scala?

Comment: With not so much pleasure (as the code is far from an elegant Scala code). Hint, hint: If the answer worked for you, please accept the answer.